# PySpark using window to create field using previous created field value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to create a new column in my df called indexCP using Window I want to take the previous value from indexCP * (current_df['return']+1) if there is no previous indexCP do 100 * (current_df['return']+1).

```
column_list = ["id","secname"]
windowval = (Window.partitionBy(column_list).orderBy(col('calendarday').cast("timestamp").cast("long")).rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('indexCP', when(spark_df["PreviousYearUnique"] == spark_df["yearUnique"], 100 * (current_df['return']+1)).otherwise(last('indexCP').over(windowval) * (current_df['return']+1)))
```

when I run the above code I get an error "AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`indexCP`' given input columns:" which I believe is saying you cant take a value that has not been created yet but I am unsure of how to fix it.

```
Starting Data Frame
## +---+-----------+----------+------------------+       
## | id|calendarday|   secName|            return|
## +---+-----------+----------+------------------+
## |  1|2015-01-01 |         1|            0.0076|
## |  1|2015-01-02 |         1|            0.0026|
## |  1|2015-01-01 |         2|            0.0016|
## |  1|2015-01-02 |         2|            0.0006|
## |  2|2015-01-01 |         3|            0.0012|
## |  2|2015-01-02 |         3|            0.0014|
## +---+----------+-----------+------------------+

New Data Frame IndexCP added
## +---+-----------+--------+---------+------------+       
## | id|calendarday| secName|   return|     IndexCP|
## +---+-----------+--------+---------+------------+
## |  1|2015-01-01 |       1|   0.0076|      100.76|(1st 100*(return+1))
## |  1|2015-01-02 |       1|   0.0026|  101.021976|(2nd 100.76*(return+1))
## |  2|2015-01-01 |       2|   0.0016|      100.16|(1st 100*(return+1))
## |  2|2015-01-02 |       2|   0.0006|  100.220096|(2nd 100.16*(return+1))
## |  3|2015-01-01 |       3|   0.0012|     100.12 |(1st 100*(return+1))
## |  3|2015-01-02 |       3|   0.0014|  100.260168|(2nd 100.12*(return+1))
## +---+----------+---------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: did the updated answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This should be the final answer, I've extended it by another row for `secName` column.

What you're looking for is a rolling product function using your formula of `IndexCP * (current_return + 1)`.
First you need to aggregate all existing returns into an `ArrayType` and then aggregate. This can be done with some Spark SQL `aggregate` function, such as:

```
column_list = ["id","secname"]
windowval = (
    Window.partitionBy(column_list)
      .orderBy(f.col('calendarday').cast("timestamp"))
      .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
)


df1.show()
+---+-----------+-------+------+
| id|calendarday|secName|return|
+---+-----------+-------+------+
|  1| 2015-01-01|      1|0.0076|
|  1| 2015-01-02|      1|0.0026|
|  1| 2015-01-03|      1|0.0014|
|  2| 2015-01-01|      2|0.0016|
|  2| 2015-01-02|      2|6.0E-4|
|  2| 2015-01-03|      2|   0.0|
|  3| 2015-01-01|      3|0.0012|
|  3| 2015-01-02|      3|0.0014|
+---+-----------+-------+------+

# f.collect_list(...) gets all your returns - this must be windowed
# cast(1 as double) is your base of 1 to begin with
# (acc, x) -> acc * (1 + x) is your formula translated to Spark SQL
# where acc is the accumulated value and x is the incoming value
df1.withColumn(
    "rolling_returns", 
    f.collect_list("return").over(windowval)
).withColumn("IndexCP", 
    100 * f.expr("""
    aggregate(
       rolling_returns,
       cast(1 as double),
       (acc, x) -> acc * (1+x))
    """)
).orderBy("id", "calendarday").show(truncate=False)

+---+-----------+-------+------+------------------------+------------------+
|id |calendarday|secName|return|rolling_returns         |IndexCP           |
+---+-----------+-------+------+------------------------+------------------+
|1  |2015-01-01 |1      |0.0076|[0.0076]                |100.76            |
|1  |2015-01-02 |1      |0.0026|[0.0076, 0.0026]        |101.021976        |
|1  |2015-01-03 |1      |0.0014|[0.0076, 0.0026, 0.0014]|101.16340676640002|
|2  |2015-01-01 |2      |0.0016|[0.0016]                |100.16000000000001|
|2  |2015-01-02 |2      |6.0E-4|[0.0016, 6.0E-4]        |100.220096        |
|2  |2015-01-03 |2      |0.0   |[0.0016, 6.0E-4, 0.0]   |100.220096        |
|3  |2015-01-01 |3      |0.0012|[0.0012]                |100.12            |
|3  |2015-01-02 |3      |0.0014|[0.0012, 0.0014]        |100.26016800000002|
+---+-----------+-------+------+------------------------+------------------+
```

Explanation: The starting value *must* be 1 and the multiplier of 100 must be on the outside of the expression, otherwise you indeed start drifting by a factor of 100 above expected returns.

I have verified the values now adhere to your formula, for instance for `secName == 1 and id == 1`:

```
100 * ((1.0026 * (0.0076 + 1)) * (0.0014 + 1)) = 101.1634067664
```

Which is indeed correct according to the formula `(acc, x) -> acc * (1+x)`. Hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the same equation that I am looking for as If i do the math out on a spread sheet with this equation the numbers don't equal.  The equation I have needs to take the previous IndexCP column if there is not one start at 100 then do * (return + 1).  It is trying to calculate the value of a stocks return compounded daily including the last value.

Comment: @CharlesP Apologies, I misunderstood the question. I've updated the answer with correct calculation based exactly on your formula.

Comment: I think i might be explaining it wrong so no worries your help is huge as I am very much so a beginner in pyspark and cant really find anything on google. Is this always doing 100 * (SUM(rolling_returns)+1) because it needs to be using the last IndexCP value as 100. (last_IndexCP * (currentReturn + 1))  While in the example i have listed we are getting the same value.  when they are more than 2 of the same secNames the numbers drift apart. I have updated the New Data Frame IndexCP Added show to try to explain it better. I'll do a test with this equation and see if they drift apart

Comment: @CharlesP can you please clarify further? I've updated with the exact same `id` and `secName` columns as you have and the formula returns all correct `IndexCP` values now. In fact, the formula `(acc, x) -> acc * (1 + x)` translates to `((last_IndexCP) * (return +1))` where `last_IndexCP` begins at `cast(100 as double)`.

Comment: The only drift I can see that the value may equal to `100.16000000000001` instead of `100.16` but this can easily be fixed by rounding to `n` decimal points - this is a common aspect of dealing with floating point decimals.

Comment: @CharlesP apologies! I was able to see the drift once I added additional rows. Hope this now fully answers your initial question! Please let me know if you're unsure about this and please accept and upvote if this is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: My mistake looks like the updated equation is right. I will have to do some more verification but looks good!  Thank you so much I thought it was adding the rolling returns together.  Is it essentially a for loop going over all rolling returns?

Comment: Sort of yes - it's not realistically a for loop, but instead a Scala map-reduce function applied in the step `(acc, x) -> acc * (1+x)`. Here, if you wish to add a cumulative sum instead, you could replace the logic with `(acc, x) -> acc + x`.